# Ruby program for string comparison

Tags: ruby

I have string comparison code in ruby in which i am getting some weird output

```
def matchval_not_pos(str1, str2)
  a1, a2 = str1.chars, str2.chars
  return 0 if a1 == a2
  [a1.size, a2.size].min.times do |i|
    if a1[i] == a2[i]
      a1.delete_at(i) 
      a2.delete_at(i)
    end
  end
  a1.reduce(0) do |t,c|
    i = a2.index(c)
    if i
      inc = 1
      a2.delete_at(i)
    else
      inc = 0
    end
    t + inc
  end
end
```

I am getting output on Pry Console

```
=> :matchval_not_pos
[12] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abc","abc")
=> 0
[13] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcd","abc")
=> 1
[14] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcde","abc")
=> 1
[15] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcdef","abc")
=> 1
[16] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcdefgh","abc")
=> 1
[17] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcdefgh","abcdefghi")
=> 4
[18] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcdefgh","abcdefghijklmn")
=> 4
[19] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcdefghijklmn","abcdefghijklmn")
=> 0
[20] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcdefghijklmnop","abcdefghijklmn")
=> 7
[21] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcdefghijklmnop","abcdefghijklmnop")
=> 0
[22] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcdefghijklmnop","abcdefghijklmnopqw")
=> 8
[23] pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcdefghijklmnop","abcdefghijklmnop")
=> 0
```

I am not able to sort it out why i am getting this output. Can someone please help me out.

Comment: What output _were_ you expecting?

Comment: If  matchval_not_pos("abc","abc")
=> 0
& pry(main)> matchval_not_pos("abcde","abc") =>
2 If you check till 3 charecters string it match properly But if i increased charector string in str1 like ("abcdefg","abcd") it gives me wrong output

Comment: One thing you might do is break `matchval_not_pos` into smaller methods and write unit tests for each method. Might actually help you debug this more quickly, plus you'll be able to test all edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read through the entire snip you posted, but I noticed this part won't work like you expect it to:

```
[a1.size, a2.size].min.times do |i|
  if a1[i] == a2[i]
    a1.delete_at(i) 
    a2.delete_at(i)
  end
end
```

The mistake here is that you're modifying an array (with `#delete_at`) at the same time as looping over it.

Ie. If you `a1.delete_at(1)`, you change the indexes of all the characters after index 1, and change the length of the array.

Basically, things get out of sync.

One solution in this case is to do `a1[i] = nil` instead of `a1.delete_at(i)` and then outside of the loop do `a1.compact!`.

Answer (score 0):

To expound on the issue stoodfarback pointed out, let's examine why removing items from an array during a loop is not the way to go in your case.

Let's say we have two arrays of the following values:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
y = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

Now let's put them through your loop:

```
[x.size, y.size].min.times do |i|
    if x[i] == y[i]
        x.delete_at(i)
        y.delete_at(i)
    end
end
```

This means we'll be looping 4 times. The first time through the loop, `i` will be `0`. So, `x[0]` is `"a"` and `y[0]` is `"a"`. This means we `.delete_at(0)` on both arrays. This means that after the first loop through, our arrays will be this:

```
x = ["b", "c", "d"]
y = ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

See what happened? We removed the first element in the arrays and now everything scoots down to fill the void. So, now we travel through the loop a second time and now `i` is `1`. We wil be looking at `x[1]` and `y[1]` which is comparing `"c"` and `"c"`. We completely skipped `"b"`.

This means you are only checking every other element.

There are many possible solutions to comparing arrays but, if you are in love with the concept of using `.delete_at`, did you consider using the method `.downto`? It would have the same affect as `.times` but it'll start at a number and work down. So:

```
([x.size, y.size].min - 1).downto(0) do |i|
    if x[i] == y[i]
        x.delete_at(i)
        y.delete_at(i)
    end
end
```

Now when we go through the loop the first time, we'll be examining the last element first. So, if we `.delete_at(3)`, it won't throw us off in the next iteration.

Again, this isn't the best solution but it is a possible solution. I agree with aceofbassgreg that you should break this up into smaller methods and provide more meaningful names to the variables.

I hope this helps you learn how removing elements from an array during a loop can provide odd results.